# Operator <= cannot be applied to operands of datetime and dateonly

Tags: c#, linq

I have some C# code which im porting over to SQL. The C# code compiles and works as expected.

I try to copy it over to LinqPad to see what SQL is generated but i get the error

***"operator <= cannot be applied to operands of DateTime and DateOnly"***

I tried to import some namespaces thinking this might be causing some confusion but that didnt help.

The breviated C# code im converting is

```
from o in organisations
where reference = ref
&& o.SubscriptionStartDate <= o.SubscriptionEndDate 
order by....
select o....
```

I copy this into LinqPad and thats when i get the error.

After some research i believe the SQL syntax is using BETWEEN (reference https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) however i would like to know why LinqPad is issuing this error in the first place?

Similar errors occur with other date types i.e. o.SubscriptionEndDate.Value.Date so i wasnt sure if this is all linked.

Could anyone clarify what i need to do in order to get rid of this error?

Comment: What's the type of `SubscriptionStartDate` and `SubscriptionEndDate`?

Comment: One column is of type DATETIME and the other column is DATE. Since your code can run, it may be because LinqPad connected to the wrong database.

Comment: *The C# code compiles and works as expected* -- That means that in Linqpad you're not in the same environment. Is it in the same .Net version + the same types? For example, what is `organisations`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with you code is that there is no overload of the `<=` operator which accepts an operand of type `DateTime` and the other operand of type `DateOnly`. Please notice that this is purely a compilation error at the C# compiler level, there is also another (possible) problem related with the runtime execution of your code which is discussed at the bottom of my answer.

If you want to compare a value of type `DateTime` and a value of type `DateOnly` with the `<=` operator you need to convert one of the two values.

There is [an overload of the `<=` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_lessthanorequal?view=net-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-aspire-8.0) which allows to compare 2 values of type `DateTime`
There is also [an overload of the `<=` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly.op_lessthanorequal?view=net-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-aspire-8.0) which allows to compare 2 values of type `DateOnly`.
You have to convert one of the 2 values to the other type and use one of the above mentioned operators.

Probably the right thing to do in your case is converting the `DateTime` value to a `DateOnly` value, which corresponds to the date part of the provided `DateTime` value. You can do this, by using the [DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.dateonly.fromdatetime?view=net-8.0).

I don't know which one among `o.SubscriptionStartDate` and `o.SubscriptionEndDate` is of type `DateTime`.
Let's suppose, as an example, that `o.SubscriptionStartDate` is of type `DateTime`; in this case you can change your code to the following:

```
from o in organisations
where reference = ref
&& DateOnly.FromDateTime(o.SubscriptionStartDate) <= o.SubscriptionEndDate
```

This version of the code will compile, since in this case you are suing the [overload of the `<=` operator which allows to compare 2 values of type `DateOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly.op_lessthanorequal?view=net-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-aspire-8.0).

If your code targets LINQ to objects this will be enough to make your code work at runtime also. If, instead, your LINQ code is used to execute a query against a database you need to try it and verify if the LINQ provider is able to translate your C# code to the query language for your database. If you get a runtime error you need to verify that the type you assigned to the properties of your object model is the right one based on the type you have used at the database level.

If, for instance, you are using SQL server and on the database you have used the [`datetime2` T-SQL type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for both the `SubscriptionStartDate` and the `SubscriptionEndDate` columns, then simply use the `System.DateTime` type for both the properties in your object model: this way your code will compile with no changes and will work at runtime also.